# Create artificial zoom transform event

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a timeline in D3 with a highly modified drag/scroll pan/zoom. The zoom callbacks use the `d3.event.transform` objects generated by the zoom behavior.

I need to add a programmatic zoom that uses my existing callbacks. I have tried and tried to do this without doing so, but I haven't gotten it to work and it would be radically easier and faster to reuse the existing structure.

So the input is a new domain, i.e. `[new Date(1800,0), new Date(2000,0)]`, and the output should be a new `d3.event.transform` that acts exactly like the output of a, say, mousewheel event.

Some example existing code:

```
this.xScale = d3.scaleTime()
  .domain(this.initialDateRange)
  .range([0, this.w]);

this.xScaleShadow = d3.scaleTime()
  .domain(this.xScale.domain())
  .range([0, this.w]);

this.zoomBehavior = d3.zoom()
  .extent([[0, 0], [this.w, this.h]])
  .on('zoom', this.zoomHandler.bind(this));

this.timelineSVG
  .call(zoomBehavior);

... 

function zoomHandler(transformEvent) {
  this.xScale.domain(transformEvent.rescaleX(this.xScaleShadow).domain());

  // update UI
  this.timeAxis.transformHandler(transformEvent);
  this.updateGraphics();
}
```

Example goal:

```
function zoomTo(extents){
  var newTransform = ?????(extents);

  zoomHandler(newTransform);
}
```

(Please don't mark as duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13248576/d3-fire-zoom-event-or-simulate-zoom-event), my question is more specific and refers to a much newer d3 API)

Comment: Have you looked at brush and zoom examples? In these the brush is used to rescale the scale and then apply a new zoom by setting a new transform  (with `selection.call(zoom.transform, zoomTransform`). Assuming I understand the question correctly, I'll fill an answer out later when I'm free later tonight.

Comment: @AndrewReid I have, but to be honest I simply don't understand the details of `zoom.transform` and other moving parts...

Answer (score 5):

Assuming I understand the problem:

Simply based on the title of your question, we can assign a zoom transform and trigger a zoom event programatically in d3v4 and d3v5 using [zoom.transform](https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom#zoom_transform), as below:

```
selection.call(zoom.transform, newTransform)
```

Where selection is the selection that the zoom was called on, `zoom` is the name of the zoom behavior object, `zoom.transform` is a function of the zoom object that sets a zoom transform that is applied on a selection (and emits start, zoom, and end events), while `newTransform` is a transformation that is provided to `zoom.transform` as a parameter (see `selection.call()` in the [docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_call) for more info on this pattern, but it is the same as `zoom.transform(selection,newTransform)`).

Below you can set a zoom on the rectangle by clicking the button: *The zoom is applied not spatially but with color, but the principles are the same when zooming on data semantically or geometrically.*

```js
var scale = d3.scaleSqrt()
  .range(["red","blue","yellow"])
  .domain([1,40,1600]);
  
var zoom = d3.zoom()
  .on("zoom", zoomed)
  .scaleExtent([1,1600])
    

var rect = d3.select("svg")
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width", 400)
  .attr("height", 200)
  .attr("fill","red")
  .call(zoom);
  
// Call zoom.transform initially to trigger zoom (otherwise current zoom isn't shown to start). 
rect.call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity);

// Call zoom.transform to set k to 100 on button push:
d3.select("button").on("click", function() {
  var newTransform = d3.zoomIdentity.scale(100);
  rect.call(zoom.transform, newTransform);
})

// Zoom function:
function zoomed(){
  var k = d3.event.transform.k;
  rect.attr("fill", scale(k));
  d3.select("#currentZoom").text(k);
}
```

```css
rect {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<button>Trigger Zoom</button> <br />
<span> Current Zoom: </span><span id="currentZoom"></span><br />
<svg></svg>
```

If applying a zoom transform to a scale, we need to rescale based on the new extent. This is similar to the brush and zoom examples that exist, but I'll break it out in a bare bones example using only a scale and an axis (you can zoom on the scale itself with the mouse too):

```js
var width = 400;
var height = 200;

var svg = d3.select("svg")
  .attr("width",width)
  .attr("height",height);
  
// The scale used to display the axis.
var scale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([0,width])
  .domain([0,100]);
  
// The reference scale
var shadowScale = scale.copy();

var axis = d3.axisBottom()
  .scale(scale);
  
var g = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform","translate(0,50)")
  .call(axis);
  
// Standard zoom behavior:
var zoom = d3.zoom()
  .scaleExtent([1,10])
  .translateExtent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
  .on("zoom", zoomed);
 
// Rect to interface with mouse for zoom events.
var rect = svg.append("rect")
  .attr("width",width)
  .attr("height",height)
  .attr("fill","none")
  .call(zoom);
  
d3.select("#extent")
  .on("click", function() {
    // Redfine the scale based on extent
    var extent = [10,20];

    // Build a new zoom transform:
    var transform = d3.zoomIdentity
      .scale( width/ ( scale(extent[1]) - scale(extent[0]) ) ) // how wide is the full domain relative to the shown domain?
      .translate(-scale(extent[0]), 0);  // Shift the transform to account for starting value
      
    // Apply the new zoom transform:
    rect.call(zoom.transform, transform);

  })
  
d3.select("#reset")
  .on("click", function() {
    // Create an identity transform
    var transform = d3.zoomIdentity;
    
    // Apply the transform:
    rect.call(zoom.transform, transform);
  })

// Handle both regular and artificial zooms:  
function zoomed() {
  var t = d3.event.transform;
  scale.domain(t.rescaleX(shadowScale).domain());
  g.call(axis);
}
```

```css
rect {
  pointer-events: all;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<button id="extent">Zoom to extent 10-20</button><button id="reset">Reset</button><br />
<svg></svg>
```

Taking a look at the key part, when we want to zoom to a certain extent we can use something along the following lines:

```
d3.select("something")
  .on("click", function() {
    // Redfine the scale based on scaled extent we want to show
    var extent = [10,20];

    // Build a new zoom transform (using d3.zoomIdentity as a base)
    var transform = d3.zoomIdentity
      // how wide is the full domain relative to the shown domain?
      .scale( width/(scale(extent[1]) - scale(extent[0])) ) 
      // Shift the transform to account for starting value
      .translate(-scale(extent[0]), 0);  

    // Apply the new zoom transform:
    rect.call(zoom.transform, transform);

  })
```

Note that by using `d3.zoomIdentity`, we can take advantage of the identity transform (with its built in methods for rescaling) and modify its scale and transform to meet our needs.

Comment: Ah ok, interesting, I think I get it now. I have this almost working—now, the programmatic zoom does work and scales correctly. However, after doing that, when I drag/scroll, the same handler gives `d3.event.transform` as `{kx: undefined, ky: undefined, x: NaN, y: NaN}`. Furthermore, if I try to do a `transition()` on the programmatic `call`, it gives undefined/NaN also, even though the non-transition one works. I'm missing something here.

Comment: Nevermind, got it, I am using d3.xyzoom for other reasons, so I had to use that library's identity instead. It's now working perfectly, thank you so much! :D