# Reset drag position after repositioning map in D3.js

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js

I have a draggable drilldown map(continent + countries). When the user click on the top-level continent map, it will drilldown to the country map.

**The problem**: The map is draggable. However, there is a odd behavior that if you drag one of the map and the drag position is effecting the other map.

For example, this is how the odd behavior gets produced:

**1**: you drag the **continent** map

**2**: you double click on the one of the continent and make map load the countries

**3**: when you drag the **country** map , the map will first jump to the dragged position of the previous **continent** map.

**What I have tried:**
Before loading a new map. I created a ResetMap function that resets all map related attributes. In that function, I have tried multiple things to reset the drag position like following:

`svg.attr("transform", null);`: This only makes it so that when it loads, it is loading correctly on the screen. But when you start to drag the new map, the previous drag position is still effecting the second map.

`svg.translate([0, 0]);`: this does not work at all

`zoom.translate([0, 0]);`: I also tried to take out the zoom function and reset it like this, this did not work as well

`svg.call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity);`: this does not work either

**What I need help with**: Understand Why is the previous drag position affecting the new map despite setting svg's transformation to null and how to fix that?

The production code is big, so I created this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/87pjwcmd/18/) to reproduce the behavior (snippet below).  When you drag the first map far off the screen and click the button to load the second map. It loads fine, but when you drag the second map, the drag position of the first map is effecting it.

```js
function roi() {
  return {
    "type": "FeatureCollection", 
    "features": [
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "Carlow" } , "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -6.592415, 52.708085 ], [ -6.614788, 52.654218 ], [ -6.717890, 52.633128 ], [ -6.810019, 52.481218 ], [ -6.916185, 52.446304 ], [ -6.914688, 52.590519 ], [ -6.975609, 52.653791 ], [ -6.952951, 52.705377 ], [ -7.090468, 52.732311 ], [ -7.072441, 52.797934 ], [ -7.065957, 52.822872 ], [ -6.915828, 52.856717 ], [ -6.735489, 52.884007 ], [ -6.712332, 52.924335 ], [ -6.463234, 52.893982 ], [ -6.512470, 52.826791 ], [ -6.631176, 52.831494 ], [ -6.592415, 52.708085 ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": {  "id": "Cavan" } , "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -7.311848, 54.114105 ], [ -7.188226, 54.079548 ], [ -7.035960, 54.086530 ], [ -6.753231, 53.901916 ], [ -6.753302, 53.900348 ], [ -6.779095, 53.873842 ], [ -6.942976, 53.874982 ], [ -6.955730, 53.766893 ], [ -7.275153, 53.783851 ], [ -7.282350, 53.795394 ], [ -7.394715, 53.781713 ], [ -7.471810, 53.835936 ], [ -7.577762, 53.872702 ], [ -7.606476, 53.937257 ], [ -7.604552, 54.005160 ], [ -7.760239, 54.105127 ], [ -7.853223, 54.098144 ], [ -8.034560, 54.238796 ], [ -7.952976, 54.306628 ], [ -7.878090, 54.289172 ], [ -7.820589, 54.199180 ], [ -7.696967, 54.202529 ], [ -7.554248, 54.127999 ], [ -7.414737, 54.150800 ], [ -7.311848, 54.114105 ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "Clare" } , "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -9.014420, 53.143721 ], [ -8.995325, 53.094486 ], [ -8.898707, 53.061852 ], [ -8.825673, 52.973357 ], [ -8.610278, 53.039336 ], [ -8.448392, 52.981622 ], [ -8.301399, 53.004138 ], [ -8.315365, 52.923338 ], [ -8.415403, 52.895906 ], [ -8.486797, 52.717419 ], [ -8.542089, 52.683432 ], [ -8.736394, 52.676235 ], [ -8.862510, 52.697896 ], [ -8.966396, 52.683717 ], [ -8.941957, 52.735161 ], [ -9.043064, 52.749839 ], [ -9.077478, 52.671817 ], [ -9.162482, 52.618450 ], [ -9.417494, 52.602062 ], [ -9.546959, 52.639326 ], [ -9.700864, 52.612108 ], [ -9.696375, 52.582325 ], [ -9.939203, 52.558170 ], [ -9.650845, 52.677945 ], [ -9.613081, 52.742927 ], [ -9.495800, 52.750694 ], [ -9.446422, 52.877095 ], [ -9.347524, 52.929893 ], [ -9.476420, 52.941507 ], [ -9.392484, 53.007914 ], [ -9.282471, 53.145146 ], [ -9.152507, 53.119566 ], [ -9.127497, 53.157615 ], [ -9.014420, 53.143721 ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "Cork" } , "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -8.160320, 52.302731 ], [ -8.088569, 52.215518 ], [ -8.137519, 52.159086 ], [ -7.927468, 51.990147 ], [ -7.849731, 51.978747 ], [ -7.904168, 51.911271 ], [ -7.865834, 51.880134 ], [ -7.997508, 51.860682 ], [ -8.001356, 51.825127 ], [ -8.170295, 51.784300 ], [ -8.264704, 51.815152 ], [ -8.202501, 51.874006 ], [ -8.319711, 51.842370 ], [ -8.273041, 51.798194 ], [ -8.339163, 51.716254 ], [ -8.563037, 51.639302 ], [ -8.658587, 51.634029 ], [ -8.706397, 51.570686 ], [ -8.867498, 51.576243 ], [ -9.107476, 51.537340 ], [ -9.227536, 51.479839 ], [ -9.535274, 51.529003 ], [ -9.644717, 51.520382 ], [ -9.773613, 51.446564 ], [ -9.838025, 51.483188 ], [ -9.653624, 51.542897 ], [ -9.539193, 51.612083 ], [ -9.850850, 51.542897 ], [ -9.444142, 51.692384 ], [ -9.451909, 51.731502 ], [ -9.639730, 51.675426 ], [ -9.906925, 51.652056 ], [ -9.935284, 51.614292 ], [ -10.166355, 51.580447 ], [ -10.055843, 51.632105 ], [ -10.097525, 51.671223 ], [ -9.974188, 51.685402 ], [ -10.004755, 51.719318 ], [ -9.908279, 51.749600 ], [ -9.856336, 51.719175 ], [ -9.727869, 51.792636 ], [ -9.595054, 51.796698 ], [ -9.330922, 51.890181 ], [ -9.305343, 51.970553 ], [ -9.153718, 52.007676 ], [ -9.229317, 52.180890 ], [ -9.294513, 52.237036 ], [ -9.234589, 52.308431 ], [ -9.132414, 52.338500 ], [ -8.961836, 52.321185 ], [ -8.842702, 52.378330 ], [ -8.640631, 52.360160 ], [ -8.519502, 52.284704 ], [ -8.341799, 52.321969 ], [ -8.160320, 52.302731 ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": {  "id": "Donegal" } , "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ -8.541947, 55.023711 ], [ -8.486370, 54.973478 ], [ -8.569735, 54.975687 ], [ -8.541947, 55.023711 ] ] ], [ [ [ -8.161674, 54.457683 ], [ -8.282019, 54.479843 ], [ -8.223093, 54.572114 ], [ -8.109161, 54.612657 ], [ -8.115787, 54.649922 ], [ -8.299190, 54.600971 ], [ -8.288075, 54.646502 ], [ -8.463070, 54.605175 ], [ -8.586978, 54.605674 ], [ -8.793609, 54.659042 ], [ -8.807504, 54.697661 ], [ -8.653100, 54.775682 ], [ -8.434142, 54.755446 ], [ -8.568595, 54.825701 ], [ -8.384194, 54.882631 ], [ -8.460292, 54.918756 ], [ -8.462999, 55.002691 ], [ -8.348639, 55.039030 ], [ -8.286365, 55.159945 ], [ -8.159750, 55.146550 ], [ -8.026366, 55.173483 ], [ -7.981405, 55.227635 ], [ -7.873601, 55.202055 ], [ -7.631913, 55.278224 ], [ -7.617520, 55.191225 ], [ -7.517482, 55.122609 ], [ -7.633623, 55.057698 ], [ -7.559165, 55.034327 ], [ -7.680864, 54.951817 ], [ -7.472522, 55.046511 ], [ -7.526959, 55.059052 ], [ -7.462476, 55.137358 ], [ -7.555816, 55.197067 ], [ -7.528028, 55.285990 ], [ -7.428631, 55.279577 ], [ -7.348116, 55.357884 ], [ -7.194710, 55.348193 ], [ -7.153597, 55.294825 ], [ -6.920745, 55.237111 ], [ -7.158585, 55.148758 ], [ -7.273871, 55.056772 ], [ -7.353103, 55.048649 ], [ -7.443024, 54.934432 ], [ -7.457987, 54.857907 ], [ -7.552467, 54.791714 ], [ -7.537362, 54.744758 ], [ -7.648658, 54.749532 ], [ -7.750619, 54.705498 ], [ -7.834412, 54.738559 ], [ -7.925259, 54.702292 ], [ -7.855289, 54.634674 ], [ -7.710647, 54.630327 ], [ -7.829211, 54.544682 ], [ -8.003280, 54.546107 ], [ -8.052729, 54.489675 ], [ -8.161674, 54.457683 ] ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "Dublin" } , "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -6.105263, 53.219391 ], [ -6.347948, 53.200936 ], [ -6.464161, 53.228939 ], [ -6.535199, 53.255302 ], [ -6.495512, 53.384126 ], [ -6.453473, 53.376858 ], [ -6.334767, 53.452528 ], [ -6.320516, 53.495493 ], [ -6.408085, 53.563468 ], [ -6.291089, 53.579998 ], [ -6.213638, 53.635504 ], [ -6.098637, 53.585128 ], [ -6.075836, 53.519006 ], [ -6.121936, 53.388757 ], [ -6.229171, 53.360470 ], [ -6.100276, 53.282877 ], [ -6.105263, 53.219391 ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "Galway" } , "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ -9.780809, 53.152057 ], [ -9.654194, 53.131822 ], [ -9.654194, 53.088500 ], [ -9.830258, 53.138163 ], [ -9.780809, 53.152057 ] ] ], [ [ [ -9.630823, 53.320711 ], [ -9.648066, 53.227371 ], [ -9.744185, 53.235138 ], [ -9.630823, 53.320711 ] ] ], [ [ [ -8.020095, 53.261501 ], [ -7.956538, 53.216256 ], [ -8.068404, 53.175642 ], [ -8.301399, 53.004138 ], [ -8.448392, 52.981622 ], [ -8.610278, 53.039336 ], [ -8.825673, 52.973357 ], [ -8.898707, 53.061852 ], [ -8.995325, 53.094486 ], [ -9.014420, 53.143721 ], [ -8.903053, 53.221528 ], [ -9.051970, 53.220175 ], [ -8.936399, 53.271547 ], [ -9.525869, 53.220958 ], [ -9.622487, 53.326269 ], [ -9.550807, 53.342372 ], [ -9.649135, 53.387119 ], [ -9.774753, 53.291498 ], [ -9.908065, 53.328763 ], [ -10.071946, 53.420678 ], [ -10.198062, 53.405145 ], [ -10.093036, 53.467063 ], [ -10.130800, 53.574868 ], [ -10.014160, 53.567885 ], [ -10.056413, 53.611492 ], [ -9.669727, 53.614912 ], [ -9.610587, 53.632725 ], [ -9.409727, 53.541095 ], [ -9.265798, 53.544301 ], [ -9.203239, 53.487442 ], [ -9.117023, 53.486800 ], [ -8.983425, 53.621895 ], [ -8.814985, 53.663292 ], [ -8.664358, 53.670916 ], [ -8.611489, 53.709535 ], [ -8.438631, 53.687660 ], [ -8.263208, 53.516085 ], [ -8.242046, 53.361040 ], [ -8.152838, 53.328478 ], [ -8.129753, 53.262427 ], [ -8.020095, 53.261501 ] ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "Kerry" } , "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ -10.349188, 51.935996 ], [ -10.286415, 51.921817 ], [ -10.430843, 51.880134 ], [ -10.349188, 51.935996 ] ] ], [ [ [ -9.328215, 52.572634 ], [ -9.303134, 52.515490 ], [ -9.339544, 52.373057 ], [ -9.234589, 52.308431 ], [ -9.294513, 52.237036 ], [ -9.229317, 52.180890 ], [ -9.153718, 52.007676 ], [ -9.305343, 51.970553 ], [ -9.330922, 51.890181 ], [ -9.595054, 51.796698 ], [ -9.727869, 51.792636 ], [ -9.856336, 51.719175 ], [ -9.908279, 51.749600 ], [ -9.863034, 51.748175 ], [ -9.745824, 51.849282 ], [ -10.125812, 51.736775 ], [ -10.228059, 51.781806 ], [ -10.208607, 51.844009 ], [ -10.343630, 51.782946 ], [ -10.335864, 51.845434 ], [ -10.408612, 51.878495 ], [ -10.252499, 51.904004 ], [ -10.321970, 51.952669 ], [ -10.258056, 51.991786 ], [ -9.916972, 52.066815 ], [ -9.889184, 52.111276 ], [ -9.753021, 52.156806 ], [ -9.985303, 52.143197 ], [ -10.193074, 52.106787 ], [ -10.287484, 52.140418 ], [ -10.452504, 52.096527 ], [ -10.475803, 52.176828 ], [ -10.361372, 52.235398 ], [ -10.178040, 52.291544 ], [ -10.181959, 52.231265 ], [ -10.026415, 52.271522 ], [ -9.955804, 52.232619 ], [ -9.736419, 52.256773 ], [ -9.876928, 52.274016 ], [ -9.833607, 52.385669 ], [ -9.943620, 52.422933 ], [ -9.828049, 52.434334 ], [ -9.687469, 52.482928 ], [ -9.620278, 52.581541 ], [ -9.364197, 52.591231 ], [ -9.328215, 52.572634 ] ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "Kildare" } , "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -6.495512, 53.384126 ], [ -6.535199, 53.255302 ], [ -6.464161, 53.228939 ], [ -6.592771, 53.092704 ], [ -6.745464, 53.017747 ], [ -6.712332, 52.924335 ], [ -6.735489, 52.884007 ], [ -6.915828, 52.856717 ], [ -6.957939, 52.967443 ], [ -7.032896, 52.971932 ], [ -7.030687, 53.080235 ], [ -7.097237, 53.164598 ], [ -6.997626, 53.317006 ], [ -7.136140, 53.409563 ], [ -7.032112, 53.514019 ], [ -6.840586, 53.390539 ], [ -6.713757, 53.426378 ], [ -6.495512, 53.384126 ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "Kilkenny" } , "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -7.072441, 52.797934 ], [ -7.090468, 52.732311 ], [ -6.952951, 52.705377 ], [ -6.975609, 52.653791 ], [ -6.914688, 52.590519 ], [ -6.916185, 52.446304 ], [ -6.975182, 52.291544 ], [ -7.191717, 52.251857 ], [ -7.338853, 52.342561 ], [ -7.400130, 52.455496 ], [ -7.386663, 52.502451 ], [ -7.454139, 52.640253 ], [ -7.649370, 52.790809 ], [ -7.559236, 52.834771 ], [ -7.414737, 52.792305 ], [ -7.284772, 52.865624 ], [ -7.181172, 52.893412 ], [ -7.065957, 52.822872 ], [ -7.072441, 52.797934 ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "Laois" } , "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -7.097237, 53.164598 ], [ -7.030687, 53.080235 ], [ -7.032896, 52.971932 ], [ -6.957939, 52.967443 ], [ -6.915828, 52.856717 ], [ -7.065957, 52.822872 ], [ -7.181172, 52.893412 ], [ -7.284772, 52.865624 ], [ -7.414737, 52.792305 ], [ -7.559236, 52.834771 ], [ -7.649370, 52.790809 ], [ -7.686564, 52.851444 ], [ -7.656923, 52.939370 ], [ -7.692264, 52.982335 ], [ -7.555246, 53.100115 ], [ -7.617948, 53.144790 ], [ -7.541708, 53.181271 ], [ -7.354813, 53.202647 ], [ -7.265606, 53.140230 ], [ -7.097237, 53.164598 ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "Leitrim" } , "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -8.282019, 54.479843 ], [ -8.161674, 54.457683 ], [ -7.952976, 54.306628 ], [ -8.034560, 54.238796 ], [ -7.853223, 54.098144 ], [ -7.760239, 54.105127 ], [ -7.604552, 54.005160 ], [ -7.606476, 53.937257 ], [ -7.663122, 53.937114 ], [ -7.822370, 53.819477 ], [ -7.899109, 53.815558 ], [ -8.000359, 53.926712 ], [ -8.100895, 53.953859 ], [ -8.040972, 54.077125 ], [ -8.133671, 54.101422 ], [ -8.170794, 54.102633 ], [ -8.333463, 54.185500 ], [ -8.310591, 54.272855 ], [ -8.377782, 54.348453 ], [ -8.373863, 54.468228 ], [ -8.282019, 54.479843 ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "Limerick" } , "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -8.160320, 52.302731 ], [ -8.341799, 52.321969 ], [ -8.519502, 52.284704 ], [ -8.640631, 52.360160 ], [ -8.842702, 52.378330 ], [ -8.961836, 52.321185 ], [ -9.132414, 52.338500 ], [ -9.234589, 52.308431 ], [ -9.339544, 52.373057 ], [ -9.303134, 52.515490 ], [ -9.328215, 52.572634 ], [ -8.987487, 52.619305 ], [ -8.958060, 52.660702 ], [ -8.638066, 52.660702 ], [ -8.736394, 52.676235 ], [ -8.542089, 52.683432 ], [ -8.486797, 52.717419 ], [ -8.358258, 52.682648 ], [ -8.257080, 52.697682 ], [ -8.180698, 52.666545 ], [ -8.197941, 52.521333 ], [ -8.399157, 52.468464 ], [ -8.388968, 52.438751 ], [ -8.230361, 52.404265 ], [ -8.160320, 52.302731 ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "Longford" } , "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -7.471810, 53.835936 ], [ -7.394715, 53.781713 ], [ -7.390725, 53.735827 ], [ -7.591442, 53.647545 ], [ -7.658348, 53.531119 ], [ -7.846454, 53.538601 ], [ -7.952620, 53.512380 ], [ -8.025938, 53.607359 ], [ -7.978912, 53.694999 ], [ -7.887424, 53.772237 ], [ -7.899109, 53.815558 ], [ -7.822370, 53.819477 ], [ -7.663122, 53.937114 ], [ -7.606476, 53.937257 ], [ -7.577762, 53.872702 ], [ -7.471810, 53.835936 ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "Louth" } , "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -6.238576, 53.778721 ], [ -6.339042, 53.722788 ], [ -6.481475, 53.722788 ], [ -6.561562, 53.771453 ], [ -6.616427, 53.861516 ], [ -6.687038, 53.875481 ], [ -6.753302, 53.900348 ], [ -6.753231, 53.901916 ], [ -6.679699, 53.909469 ], [ -6.584434, 54.051902 ], [ -6.470146, 54.078835 ], [ -6.374739, 54.066366 ], [ -6.279760, 54.109901 ], [ -6.100846, 53.999603 ], [ -6.164688, 53.976802 ], [ -6.352508, 54.011502 ], [ -6.377518, 53.955711 ], [ -6.333627, 53.877049 ], [ -6.238576, 53.861801 ], [ -6.238576, 53.778721 ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "Mayo" } , "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -9.138043, 54.130707 ], [ -8.963404, 54.145527 ], [ -9.027317, 54.030241 ], [ -8.913598, 54.017701 ], [ -8.835078, 53.972455 ], [ -8.661294, 54.025681 ], [ -8.590398, 53.968109 ], [ -8.682599, 53.958704 ], [ -8.608211, 53.885884 ], [ -8.690223, 53.874484 ], [ -8.696279, 53.722716 ], [ -8.814985, 53.663292 ], [ -8.983425, 53.621895 ], [ -9.117023, 53.486800 ], [ -9.203239, 53.487442 ], [ -9.265798, 53.544301 ], [ -9.409727, 53.541095 ], [ -9.610587, 53.632725 ], [ -9.669727, 53.614912 ], [ -9.774183, 53.600661 ], [ -9.915832, 53.656238 ], [ -9.912483, 53.752286 ], [ -9.651272, 53.800453 ], [ -9.554084, 53.889874 ], [ -9.764706, 53.900134 ], [ -9.905857, 53.861231 ], [ -10.066388, 53.971814 ], [ -10.259196, 53.973453 ], [ -10.189155, 54.015706 ], [ -10.100803, 54.000671 ], [ -9.974188, 54.030669 ], [ -9.966421, 53.951009 ], [ -9.838025, 53.960414 ], [ -9.993639, 54.102633 ], [ -9.899729, 54.117953 ], [ -10.012521, 54.226541 ], [ -10.010312, 54.181296 ], [ -10.129161, 54.096007 ], [ -10.055843, 54.218204 ], [ -10.109709, 54.238511 ], [ -9.995777, 54.309336 ], [ -9.880277, 54.257607 ], [ -9.805819, 54.344606 ], [ -9.382509, 54.294302 ], [ -9.341967, 54.327363 ], [ -9.211931, 54.285894 ], [ -9.224187, 54.217136 ], [ -9.159703, 54.201816 ], [ -9.138043, 54.130707 ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "Meath" } , "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -6.687038, 53.875481 ], [ -6.616427, 53.861516 ], [ -6.561562, 53.771453 ], [ -6.481475, 53.722788 ], [ -6.339042, 53.722788 ], [ -6.238576, 53.778721 ], [ -6.213638, 53.635504 ], [ -6.291089, 53.579998 ], [ -6.408085, 53.563468 ], [ -6.320516, 53.495493 ], [ -6.334767, 53.452528 ], [ -6.453473, 53.376858 ], [ -6.495512, 53.384126 ], [ -6.713757, 53.426378 ], [ -6.840586, 53.390539 ], [ -7.032112, 53.514019 ], [ -6.962926, 53.639494 ], [ -7.250928, 53.711387 ], [ -7.275153, 53.783851 ], [ -6.955730, 53.766893 ], [ -6.942976, 53.874982 ], [ -6.779095, 53.873842 ], [ -6.753302, 53.900348 ], [ -6.687038, 53.875481 ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "Monaghan" } , "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -6.584434, 54.051902 ], [ -6.679699, 53.909469 ], [ -6.753231, 53.901916 ], [ -7.035960, 54.086530 ], [ -7.188226, 54.079548 ], [ -7.311848, 54.114105 ], [ -7.237746, 54.203455 ], [ -7.142268, 54.227325 ], [ -7.202120, 54.297722 ], [ -7.025129, 54.416143 ], [ -6.876141, 54.345247 ], [ -6.795555, 54.211649 ], [ -6.636377, 54.172745 ], [ -6.670293, 54.070570 ], [ -6.584434, 54.051902 ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "Offaly" } , "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -6.997626, 53.317006 ], [ -7.097237, 53.164598 ], [ -7.265606, 53.140230 ], [ -7.354813, 53.202647 ], [ -7.541708, 53.181271 ], [ -7.617948, 53.144790 ], [ -7.555246, 53.100115 ], [ -7.692264, 52.982335 ], [ -7.822513, 52.956256 ], [ -7.922337, 52.862560 ], [ -8.013326, 52.909729 ], [ -7.956681, 52.952907 ], [ -7.904738, 53.092491 ], [ -8.068404, 53.175642 ], [ -7.956538, 53.216256 ], [ -8.020095, 53.261501 ], [ -8.021734, 53.303326 ], [ -7.915640, 53.353416 ], [ -7.767649, 53.329048 ], [ -7.586953, 53.383770 ], [ -7.535224, 53.333751 ], [ -7.372769, 53.317719 ], [ -7.337927, 53.350709 ], [ -7.136140, 53.409563 ], [ -6.997626, 53.317006 ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "Roscommon" } , "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -8.133671, 54.101422 ], [ -8.040972, 54.077125 ], [ -8.100895, 53.953859 ], [ -8.000359, 53.926712 ], [ -7.899109, 53.815558 ], [ -7.887424, 53.772237 ], [ -7.978912, 53.694999 ], [ -8.025938, 53.607359 ], [ -7.952620, 53.512380 ], [ -7.915640, 53.353416 ], [ -8.021734, 53.303326 ], [ -8.020095, 53.261501 ], [ -8.129753, 53.262427 ], [ -8.152838, 53.328478 ], [ -8.242046, 53.361040 ], [ -8.263208, 53.516085 ], [ -8.438631, 53.687660 ], [ -8.611489, 53.709535 ], [ -8.664358, 53.670916 ], [ -8.814985, 53.663292 ], [ -8.696279, 53.722716 ], [ -8.690223, 53.874484 ], [ -8.608211, 53.885884 ], [ -8.682599, 53.958704 ], [ -8.590398, 53.968109 ], [ -8.459722, 53.916024 ], [ -8.373008, 53.919088 ], [ -8.275606, 54.047627 ], [ -8.170794, 54.102633 ], [ -8.133671, 54.101422 ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "Sligo" } , "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -8.373863, 54.468228 ], [ -8.377782, 54.348453 ], [ -8.310591, 54.272855 ], [ -8.333463, 54.185500 ], [ -8.170794, 54.102633 ], [ -8.275606, 54.047627 ], [ -8.373008, 53.919088 ], [ -8.459722, 53.916024 ], [ -8.590398, 53.968109 ], [ -8.661294, 54.025681 ], [ -8.835078, 53.972455 ], [ -8.913598, 54.017701 ], [ -9.027317, 54.030241 ], [ -8.963404, 54.145527 ], [ -9.138043, 54.130707 ], [ -9.057528, 54.295442 ], [ -8.930271, 54.294302 ], [ -8.827526, 54.253474 ], [ -8.661935, 54.272641 ], [ -8.583629, 54.207944 ], [ -8.508601, 54.217349 ], [ -8.626381, 54.255113 ], [ -8.681886, 54.355935 ], [ -8.490289, 54.418209 ], [ -8.469697, 54.470437 ], [ -8.373863, 54.468228 ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "Tipperary" } , "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -8.013326, 52.909729 ], [ -7.922337, 52.862560 ], [ -7.822513, 52.956256 ], [ -7.692264, 52.982335 ], [ -7.656923, 52.939370 ], [ -7.686564, 52.851444 ], [ -7.649370, 52.790809 ], [ -7.454139, 52.640253 ], [ -7.386663, 52.502451 ], [ -7.400130, 52.455496 ], [ -7.338853, 52.342561 ], [ -7.545271, 52.355671 ], [ -7.760524, 52.314986 ], [ -7.722190, 52.222216 ], [ -7.944426, 52.236466 ], [ -8.088569, 52.215518 ], [ -8.160320, 52.302731 ], [ -8.230361, 52.404265 ], [ -8.388968, 52.438751 ], [ -8.399157, 52.468464 ], [ -8.197941, 52.521333 ], [ -8.180698, 52.666545 ], [ -8.257080, 52.697682 ], [ -8.358258, 52.682648 ], [ -8.486797, 52.717419 ], [ -8.415403, 52.895906 ], [ -8.315365, 52.923338 ], [ -8.301399, 53.004138 ], [ -8.068404, 53.175642 ], [ -7.904738, 53.092491 ], [ -7.956681, 52.952907 ], [ -8.013326, 52.909729 ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "Waterford" } , "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -7.545271, 52.355671 ], [ -7.338853, 52.342561 ], [ -7.191717, 52.251857 ], [ -6.975182, 52.291544 ], [ -6.958651, 52.241525 ], [ -6.949175, 52.177612 ], [ -7.019714, 52.134006 ], [ -7.088615, 52.150679 ], [ -7.426921, 52.129588 ], [ -7.551398, 52.077645 ], [ -7.585243, 51.991501 ], [ -7.731951, 51.937635 ], [ -7.849731, 51.978747 ], [ -7.927468, 51.990147 ], [ -8.137519, 52.159086 ], [ -8.088569, 52.215518 ], [ -7.944426, 52.236466 ], [ -7.722190, 52.222216 ], [ -7.760524, 52.314986 ], [ -7.545271, 52.355671 ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "Westmeath" } , "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -7.282350, 53.795394 ], [ -7.275153, 53.783851 ], [ -7.250928, 53.711387 ], [ -6.962926, 53.639494 ], [ -7.032112, 53.514019 ], [ -7.136140, 53.409563 ], [ -7.337927, 53.350709 ], [ -7.372769, 53.317719 ], [ -7.535224, 53.333751 ], [ -7.586953, 53.383770 ], [ -7.767649, 53.329048 ], [ -7.915640, 53.353416 ], [ -7.952620, 53.512380 ], [ -7.846454, 53.538601 ], [ -7.658348, 53.531119 ], [ -7.591442, 53.647545 ], [ -7.390725, 53.735827 ], [ -7.394715, 53.781713 ], [ -7.282350, 53.795394 ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "Wexford" } , "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -6.958651, 52.241525 ], [ -6.975182, 52.291544 ], [ -6.916185, 52.446304 ], [ -6.810019, 52.481218 ], [ -6.717890, 52.633128 ], [ -6.614788, 52.654218 ], [ -6.592415, 52.708085 ], [ -6.446419, 52.698466 ], [ -6.325575, 52.799145 ], [ -6.144666, 52.770716 ], [ -6.225822, 52.648447 ], [ -6.193046, 52.562944 ], [ -6.353577, 52.408469 ], [ -6.358066, 52.344271 ], [ -6.465799, 52.377902 ], [ -6.429176, 52.293753 ], [ -6.311396, 52.240955 ], [ -6.358636, 52.174049 ], [ -6.489170, 52.190722 ], [ -6.596975, 52.169561 ], [ -6.706917, 52.217656 ], [ -6.836382, 52.216801 ], [ -6.823058, 52.174833 ], [ -6.931361, 52.122392 ], [ -6.903644, 52.201268 ], [ -6.958651, 52.241525 ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "Wicklow" } , "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -6.347948, 53.200936 ], [ -6.105263, 53.219391 ], [ -6.041421, 53.117928 ], [ -6.046409, 52.989887 ], [ -5.996960, 52.963738 ], [ -6.057524, 52.857358 ], [ -6.144666, 52.770716 ], [ -6.325575, 52.799145 ], [ -6.446419, 52.698466 ], [ -6.592415, 52.708085 ], [ -6.631176, 52.831494 ], [ -6.512470, 52.826791 ], [ -6.463234, 52.893982 ], [ -6.712332, 52.924335 ], [ -6.745464, 53.017747 ], [ -6.592771, 53.092704 ], [ -6.464161, 53.228939 ], [ -6.347948, 53.200936 ] ] ] } }
    ]
  }
}

function newMap(){
  return {
    "type": "FeatureCollection", 
    "features": [
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "Carlow" } , "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -6.592415, 52.708085 ], [ -6.614788, 52.654218 ], [ -6.717890, 52.633128 ], [ -6.810019, 52.481218 ], [ -6.916185, 52.446304 ], [ -6.914688, 52.590519 ], [ -6.975609, 52.653791 ], [ -6.952951, 52.705377 ], [ -7.090468, 52.732311 ], [ -7.072441, 52.797934 ], [ -7.065957, 52.822872 ], [ -6.915828, 52.856717 ], [ -6.735489, 52.884007 ], [ -6.712332, 52.924335 ], [ -6.463234, 52.893982 ], [ -6.512470, 52.826791 ], [ -6.631176, 52.831494 ], [ -6.592415, 52.708085 ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": {  "id": "Cavan" } , "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -7.311848, 54.114105 ], [ -7.188226, 54.079548 ], [ -7.035960, 54.086530 ], [ -6.753231, 53.901916 ], [ -6.753302, 53.900348 ], [ -6.779095, 53.873842 ], [ -6.942976, 53.874982 ], [ -6.955730, 53.766893 ], [ -7.275153, 53.783851 ], [ -7.282350, 53.795394 ], [ -7.394715, 53.781713 ], [ -7.471810, 53.835936 ], [ -7.577762, 53.872702 ], [ -7.606476, 53.937257 ], [ -7.604552, 54.005160 ], [ -7.760239, 54.105127 ], [ -7.853223, 54.098144 ], [ -8.034560, 54.238796 ], [ -7.952976, 54.306628 ], [ -7.878090, 54.289172 ], [ -7.820589, 54.199180 ], [ -7.696967, 54.202529 ], [ -7.554248, 54.127999 ], [ -7.414737, 54.150800 ], [ -7.311848, 54.114105 ] ] ] } }
    ]
  }
}
let cleanHover = function () {
    d3.selectAll("path")
        .transition()
        .duration(200)
        .style("stroke", "transparent")
}

let mouseOver = function (event, d) {
    var countryCode = event.target.id;
    cleanHover();
    d3.selectAll("path#" + countryCode)
        .transition()
        .duration(200)
        .style("opacity", 1)
        .style("stroke", "black")

    tip.show(event, d);

}

let mouseLeave = function () {
    cleanHover();
    tip.hide();
}

let resetMap = function(){
    svg.selectAll("*").remove();
    svg.call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity);
}

let loadSmallMap = function(){
    resetMap();
  const mapJson = newMap();
  var projection = d3.geoMercator();
  var features = mapJson.features;

  //Projections
  var geoPath = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);

  projection.fitSize([width, height], { "type": "FeatureCollection", "features": features })

  svg.selectAll("path")
    .data(features)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", geoPath)
    .attr("id", function (d) { return d.properties.id })
    .style("fill", 'steelblue')
    .style("stroke", "transparent")
    .on("mouseover", mouseOver)
    .on("mouseleave", mouseLeave)
    .call(tip);
}

    var zoom = d3.zoom()
        .on('zoom', (event) => {
            svg.attr('transform', event.transform);
        })
        .scaleExtent([1, 1]);
    var width = 560;
    var height = 350;

    var svg = d3.select("#mapDiv")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .style("background-color", "white")
        .style("border", "solid 1px black")
        .call(zoom)
        .append("g");

    const tip = d3.tip()
        .attr("class", "d3-tip")
        .html((event, d) => "red"); 

        const mapJson = roi();
        var projection = d3.geoMercator();
        var features = mapJson.features;

        //Projections
        var geoPath = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);

        projection.fitSize([width, height], { "type": "FeatureCollection", "features": features })

        svg.selectAll("path")
            .data(features)
            .enter()
            .append("path")
            .attr("d", geoPath)
            .attr("id", function (d) { return d.properties.id })
            .style("fill", 'steelblue')
            .style("stroke", "transparent")
            .on("mouseover", mouseOver)
            .on("mouseleave", mouseLeave)
            .call(tip);
```

```html
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/bumbeishvili/d3-tip-for-v6@4/d3-tip.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/bumbeishvili/d3-tip-for-v6@4/d3-tip.min.css">
<center id="mapDiv">
<input id="button" type="button" value="Load Small Map" onclick="loadSmallMap()"/>
</center>
```

Comment: You are changing the transform attribute of the SVG in the reset map function, but the zoom doesn't track that - it still thinks you are zoomed in somewhere, so the next zoom is relative to that. Instead of setting the transform to null, try `.call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity)`, which will trigger a zoom event that sets the scale to 1 and the translate to 0,0. See ["Create Artificial Zoom Event"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55931250/7106086) or ["D3 zoom jumps ... after programmatic zoom"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55481420/7106086) for more info on this problem.

Comment: You'll need to use a variable to hold the zoom behavior (`zoom` in the comment above). If you are having trouble implementing, I might be able to expand on an answer later.

Comment: @AndrewReid Unfortunatley `svg.call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity) did not work for me`. I have updated my jsfiddle, and I have also found the [doc](https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom/blob/main/README.md#zoom_transform) here  and I am not sure why at this point.

Comment: Ah, the issue is you originally call the zoom on the svg element, then in the reset map on the g element (in the selection named `svg`) , if you switch the chaining so that you have `...append("g").call(zoom)` instead of `...call(zoom).append("g")` when appending the zoom you should be good, I can write an answer later if you want - just preoccupied at the moment.

Comment: @AndrewReid There are few problems with chaining `append('g')` first. 1: the map is no longer draggable if I am dragging on empty space.(which I wanted to preserve that behavior for usability) 2: when dragging, the path is vibrating somehow. Please take your time to do whatever you need to do. I would appreciate if you could write an answer later when you get a chance. Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> svg.attr("transform", null);: This only makes it so that when it
> loads, it is loading correctly on the screen. But when you start to
> drag the new map, the previous drag position is still effecting the
> second map.

Re-iterating the comments, when you modify a SVG transform attribute manually, as you have, the zoom behavior is left in the dark. It picks up on the next zoom event based on what it thinks the zoom state is, not to what you've set it. Not all zooms will modify a transform attribute so there is no reason for it to check the zoom transform as a relative starting point for the zoom - the zoom behavior just tracks the zoom state and lets you do with it what you want.

You've updated the snippet to implement a `selection.call(zoom.transform, zoomTransform)` approach. This will trigger a zoom with the specified transform - but a problem remains. The issue is that you are calling that on a different selection than you call the zoom behavior on originally. The zoom behavior is called on the `svg` but the transform is called on the `g` (labelled as variable `svg` , but actually is a `g`). Now I know I just said the zoom  behavior tracks the zoom state - but it doesn't do so internally. It tracks it as a property of the element it is called on (you could call the same behavior on many elements and have different zoom states for each). So we still have a communication problem: the zoom transform is being called on a different element than the zoom behavior - the zoom behavior doesn't know that it's frame of reference has been changed.

The easiest solution would then be to modify the reset function to select the SVG element directly and apply the zoom transform to it instead of the g:

```
let resetMap = function(){
    svg.selectAll("*").remove();
    d3.select("svg").call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity);
}
```

```js
function roi() {
  return {
    "type": "FeatureCollection", 
    "features": [
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "Carlow" } , "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -6.592415, 52.708085 ], [ -6.614788, 52.654218 ], [ -6.717890, 52.633128 ], [ -6.810019, 52.481218 ], [ -6.916185, 52.446304 ], [ -6.914688, 52.590519 ], [ -6.975609, 52.653791 ], [ -6.952951, 52.705377 ], [ -7.090468, 52.732311 ], [ -7.072441, 52.797934 ], [ -7.065957, 52.822872 ], [ -6.915828, 52.856717 ], [ -6.735489, 52.884007 ], [ -6.712332, 52.924335 ], [ -6.463234, 52.893982 ], [ -6.512470, 52.826791 ], [ -6.631176, 52.831494 ], [ -6.592415, 52.708085 ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": {  "id": "Cavan" } , "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -7.311848, 54.114105 ], [ -7.188226, 54.079548 ], [ -7.035960, 54.086530 ], [ -6.753231, 53.901916 ], [ -6.753302, 53.900348 ], [ -6.779095, 53.873842 ], [ -6.942976, 53.874982 ], [ -6.955730, 53.766893 ], [ -7.275153, 53.783851 ], [ -7.282350, 53.795394 ], [ -7.394715, 53.781713 ], [ -7.471810, 53.835936 ], [ -7.577762, 53.872702 ], [ -7.606476, 53.937257 ], [ -7.604552, 54.005160 ], [ -7.760239, 54.105127 ], [ -7.853223, 54.098144 ], [ -8.034560, 54.238796 ], [ -7.952976, 54.306628 ], [ -7.878090, 54.289172 ], [ -7.820589, 54.199180 ], [ -7.696967, 54.202529 ], [ -7.554248, 54.127999 ], [ -7.414737, 54.150800 ], [ -7.311848, 54.114105 ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "Clare" } , "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -9.014420, 53.143721 ], [ -8.995325, 53.094486 ], [ -8.898707, 53.061852 ], [ -8.825673, 52.973357 ], [ -8.610278, 53.039336 ], [ -8.448392, 52.981622 ], [ -8.301399, 53.004138 ], [ -8.315365, 52.923338 ], [ -8.415403, 52.895906 ], [ -8.486797, 52.717419 ], [ -8.542089, 52.683432 ], [ -8.736394, 52.676235 ], [ -8.862510, 52.697896 ], [ -8.966396, 52.683717 ], [ -8.941957, 52.735161 ], [ -9.043064, 52.749839 ], [ -9.077478, 52.671817 ], [ -9.162482, 52.618450 ], [ -9.417494, 52.602062 ], [ -9.546959, 52.639326 ], [ -9.700864, 52.612108 ], [ -9.696375, 52.582325 ], [ -9.939203, 52.558170 ], [ -9.650845, 52.677945 ], [ -9.613081, 52.742927 ], [ -9.495800, 52.750694 ], [ -9.446422, 52.877095 ], [ -9.347524, 52.929893 ], [ -9.476420, 52.941507 ], [ -9.392484, 53.007914 ], [ -9.282471, 53.145146 ], [ -9.152507, 53.119566 ], [ -9.127497, 53.157615 ], [ -9.014420, 53.143721 ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "Cork" } , "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -8.160320, 52.302731 ], [ -8.088569, 52.215518 ], [ -8.137519, 52.159086 ], [ -7.927468, 51.990147 ], [ -7.849731, 51.978747 ], [ -7.904168, 51.911271 ], [ -7.865834, 51.880134 ], [ -7.997508, 51.860682 ], [ -8.001356, 51.825127 ], [ -8.170295, 51.784300 ], [ -8.264704, 51.815152 ], [ -8.202501, 51.874006 ], [ -8.319711, 51.842370 ], [ -8.273041, 51.798194 ], [ -8.339163, 51.716254 ], [ -8.563037, 51.639302 ], [ -8.658587, 51.634029 ], [ -8.706397, 51.570686 ], [ -8.867498, 51.576243 ], [ -9.107476, 51.537340 ], [ -9.227536, 51.479839 ], [ -9.535274, 51.529003 ], [ -9.644717, 51.520382 ], [ -9.773613, 51.446564 ], [ -9.838025, 51.483188 ], [ -9.653624, 51.542897 ], [ -9.539193, 51.612083 ], [ -9.850850, 51.542897 ], [ -9.444142, 51.692384 ], [ -9.451909, 51.731502 ], [ -9.639730, 51.675426 ], [ -9.906925, 51.652056 ], [ -9.935284, 51.614292 ], [ -10.166355, 51.580447 ], [ -10.055843, 51.632105 ], [ -10.097525, 51.671223 ], [ -9.974188, 51.685402 ], [ -10.004755, 51.719318 ], [ -9.908279, 51.749600 ], [ -9.856336, 51.719175 ], [ -9.727869, 51.792636 ], [ -9.595054, 51.796698 ], [ -9.330922, 51.890181 ], [ -9.305343, 51.970553 ], [ -9.153718, 52.007676 ], [ -9.229317, 52.180890 ], [ -9.294513, 52.237036 ], [ -9.234589, 52.308431 ], [ -9.132414, 52.338500 ], [ -8.961836, 52.321185 ], [ -8.842702, 52.378330 ], [ -8.640631, 52.360160 ], [ -8.519502, 52.284704 ], [ -8.341799, 52.321969 ], [ -8.160320, 52.302731 ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": {  "id": "Donegal" } , "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ -8.541947, 55.023711 ], [ -8.486370, 54.973478 ], [ -8.569735, 54.975687 ], [ -8.541947, 55.023711 ] ] ], [ [ [ -8.161674, 54.457683 ], [ -8.282019, 54.479843 ], [ -8.223093, 54.572114 ], [ -8.109161, 54.612657 ], [ -8.115787, 54.649922 ], [ -8.299190, 54.600971 ], [ -8.288075, 54.646502 ], [ -8.463070, 54.605175 ], [ -8.586978, 54.605674 ], [ -8.793609, 54.659042 ], [ -8.807504, 54.697661 ], [ -8.653100, 54.775682 ], [ -8.434142, 54.755446 ], [ -8.568595, 54.825701 ], [ -8.384194, 54.882631 ], [ -8.460292, 54.918756 ], [ -8.462999, 55.002691 ], [ -8.348639, 55.039030 ], [ -8.286365, 55.159945 ], [ -8.159750, 55.146550 ], [ -8.026366, 55.173483 ], [ -7.981405, 55.227635 ], [ -7.873601, 55.202055 ], [ -7.631913, 55.278224 ], [ -7.617520, 55.191225 ], [ -7.517482, 55.122609 ], [ -7.633623, 55.057698 ], [ -7.559165, 55.034327 ], [ -7.680864, 54.951817 ], [ -7.472522, 55.046511 ], [ -7.526959, 55.059052 ], [ -7.462476, 55.137358 ], [ -7.555816, 55.197067 ], [ -7.528028, 55.285990 ], [ -7.428631, 55.279577 ], [ -7.348116, 55.357884 ], [ -7.194710, 55.348193 ], [ -7.153597, 55.294825 ], [ -6.920745, 55.237111 ], [ -7.158585, 55.148758 ], [ -7.273871, 55.056772 ], [ -7.353103, 55.048649 ], [ -7.443024, 54.934432 ], [ -7.457987, 54.857907 ], [ -7.552467, 54.791714 ], [ -7.537362, 54.744758 ], [ -7.648658, 54.749532 ], [ -7.750619, 54.705498 ], [ -7.834412, 54.738559 ], [ -7.925259, 54.702292 ], [ -7.855289, 54.634674 ], [ -7.710647, 54.630327 ], [ -7.829211, 54.544682 ], [ -8.003280, 54.546107 ], [ -8.052729, 54.489675 ], [ -8.161674, 54.457683 ] ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "Dublin" } , "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -6.105263, 53.219391 ], [ -6.347948, 53.200936 ], [ -6.464161, 53.228939 ], [ -6.535199, 53.255302 ], [ -6.495512, 53.384126 ], [ -6.453473, 53.376858 ], [ -6.334767, 53.452528 ], [ -6.320516, 53.495493 ], [ -6.408085, 53.563468 ], [ -6.291089, 53.579998 ], [ -6.213638, 53.635504 ], [ -6.098637, 53.585128 ], [ -6.075836, 53.519006 ], [ -6.121936, 53.388757 ], [ -6.229171, 53.360470 ], [ -6.100276, 53.282877 ], [ -6.105263, 53.219391 ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "Galway" } , "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ -9.780809, 53.152057 ], [ -9.654194, 53.131822 ], [ -9.654194, 53.088500 ], [ -9.830258, 53.138163 ], [ -9.780809, 53.152057 ] ] ], [ [ [ -9.630823, 53.320711 ], [ -9.648066, 53.227371 ], [ -9.744185, 53.235138 ], [ -9.630823, 53.320711 ] ] ], [ [ [ -8.020095, 53.261501 ], [ -7.956538, 53.216256 ], [ -8.068404, 53.175642 ], [ -8.301399, 53.004138 ], [ -8.448392, 52.981622 ], [ -8.610278, 53.039336 ], [ -8.825673, 52.973357 ], [ -8.898707, 53.061852 ], [ -8.995325, 53.094486 ], [ -9.014420, 53.143721 ], [ -8.903053, 53.221528 ], [ -9.051970, 53.220175 ], [ -8.936399, 53.271547 ], [ -9.525869, 53.220958 ], [ -9.622487, 53.326269 ], [ -9.550807, 53.342372 ], [ -9.649135, 53.387119 ], [ -9.774753, 53.291498 ], [ -9.908065, 53.328763 ], [ -10.071946, 53.420678 ], [ -10.198062, 53.405145 ], [ -10.093036, 53.467063 ], [ -10.130800, 53.574868 ], [ -10.014160, 53.567885 ], [ -10.056413, 53.611492 ], [ -9.669727, 53.614912 ], [ -9.610587, 53.632725 ], [ -9.409727, 53.541095 ], [ -9.265798, 53.544301 ], [ -9.203239, 53.487442 ], [ -9.117023, 53.486800 ], [ -8.983425, 53.621895 ], [ -8.814985, 53.663292 ], [ -8.664358, 53.670916 ], [ -8.611489, 53.709535 ], [ -8.438631, 53.687660 ], [ -8.263208, 53.516085 ], [ -8.242046, 53.361040 ], [ -8.152838, 53.328478 ], [ -8.129753, 53.262427 ], [ -8.020095, 53.261501 ] ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "Kerry" } , "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ -10.349188, 51.935996 ], [ -10.286415, 51.921817 ], [ -10.430843, 51.880134 ], [ -10.349188, 51.935996 ] ] ], [ [ [ -9.328215, 52.572634 ], [ -9.303134, 52.515490 ], [ -9.339544, 52.373057 ], [ -9.234589, 52.308431 ], [ -9.294513, 52.237036 ], [ -9.229317, 52.180890 ], [ -9.153718, 52.007676 ], [ -9.305343, 51.970553 ], [ -9.330922, 51.890181 ], [ -9.595054, 51.796698 ], [ -9.727869, 51.792636 ], [ -9.856336, 51.719175 ], [ -9.908279, 51.749600 ], [ -9.863034, 51.748175 ], [ -9.745824, 51.849282 ], [ -10.125812, 51.736775 ], [ -10.228059, 51.781806 ], [ -10.208607, 51.844009 ], [ -10.343630, 51.782946 ], [ -10.335864, 51.845434 ], [ -10.408612, 51.878495 ], [ -10.252499, 51.904004 ], [ -10.321970, 51.952669 ], [ -10.258056, 51.991786 ], [ -9.916972, 52.066815 ], [ -9.889184, 52.111276 ], [ -9.753021, 52.156806 ], [ -9.985303, 52.143197 ], [ -10.193074, 52.106787 ], [ -10.287484, 52.140418 ], [ -10.452504, 52.096527 ], [ -10.475803, 52.176828 ], [ -10.361372, 52.235398 ], [ -10.178040, 52.291544 ], [ -10.181959, 52.231265 ], [ -10.026415, 52.271522 ], [ -9.955804, 52.232619 ], [ -9.736419, 52.256773 ], [ -9.876928, 52.274016 ], [ -9.833607, 52.385669 ], [ -9.943620, 52.422933 ], [ -9.828049, 52.434334 ], [ -9.687469, 52.482928 ], [ -9.620278, 52.581541 ], [ -9.364197, 52.591231 ], [ -9.328215, 52.572634 ] ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "Kildare" } , "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -6.495512, 53.384126 ], [ -6.535199, 53.255302 ], [ -6.464161, 53.228939 ], [ -6.592771, 53.092704 ], [ -6.745464, 53.017747 ], [ -6.712332, 52.924335 ], [ -6.735489, 52.884007 ], [ -6.915828, 52.856717 ], [ -6.957939, 52.967443 ], [ -7.032896, 52.971932 ], [ -7.030687, 53.080235 ], [ -7.097237, 53.164598 ], [ -6.997626, 53.317006 ], [ -7.136140, 53.409563 ], [ -7.032112, 53.514019 ], [ -6.840586, 53.390539 ], [ -6.713757, 53.426378 ], [ -6.495512, 53.384126 ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "Kilkenny" } , "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -7.072441, 52.797934 ], [ -7.090468, 52.732311 ], [ -6.952951, 52.705377 ], [ -6.975609, 52.653791 ], [ -6.914688, 52.590519 ], [ -6.916185, 52.446304 ], [ -6.975182, 52.291544 ], [ -7.191717, 52.251857 ], [ -7.338853, 52.342561 ], [ -7.400130, 52.455496 ], [ -7.386663, 52.502451 ], [ -7.454139, 52.640253 ], [ -7.649370, 52.790809 ], [ -7.559236, 52.834771 ], [ -7.414737, 52.792305 ], [ -7.284772, 52.865624 ], [ -7.181172, 52.893412 ], [ -7.065957, 52.822872 ], [ -7.072441, 52.797934 ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "Laois" } , "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -7.097237, 53.164598 ], [ -7.030687, 53.080235 ], [ -7.032896, 52.971932 ], [ -6.957939, 52.967443 ], [ -6.915828, 52.856717 ], [ -7.065957, 52.822872 ], [ -7.181172, 52.893412 ], [ -7.284772, 52.865624 ], [ -7.414737, 52.792305 ], [ -7.559236, 52.834771 ], [ -7.649370, 52.790809 ], [ -7.686564, 52.851444 ], [ -7.656923, 52.939370 ], [ -7.692264, 52.982335 ], [ -7.555246, 53.100115 ], [ -7.617948, 53.144790 ], [ -7.541708, 53.181271 ], [ -7.354813, 53.202647 ], [ -7.265606, 53.140230 ], [ -7.097237, 53.164598 ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "Leitrim" } , "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -8.282019, 54.479843 ], [ -8.161674, 54.457683 ], [ -7.952976, 54.306628 ], [ -8.034560, 54.238796 ], [ -7.853223, 54.098144 ], [ -7.760239, 54.105127 ], [ -7.604552, 54.005160 ], [ -7.606476, 53.937257 ], [ -7.663122, 53.937114 ], [ -7.822370, 53.819477 ], [ -7.899109, 53.815558 ], [ -8.000359, 53.926712 ], [ -8.100895, 53.953859 ], [ -8.040972, 54.077125 ], [ -8.133671, 54.101422 ], [ -8.170794, 54.102633 ], [ -8.333463, 54.185500 ], [ -8.310591, 54.272855 ], [ -8.377782, 54.348453 ], [ -8.373863, 54.468228 ], [ -8.282019, 54.479843 ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "Limerick" } , "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -8.160320, 52.302731 ], [ -8.341799, 52.321969 ], [ -8.519502, 52.284704 ], [ -8.640631, 52.360160 ], [ -8.842702, 52.378330 ], [ -8.961836, 52.321185 ], [ -9.132414, 52.338500 ], [ -9.234589, 52.308431 ], [ -9.339544, 52.373057 ], [ -9.303134, 52.515490 ], [ -9.328215, 52.572634 ], [ -8.987487, 52.619305 ], [ -8.958060, 52.660702 ], [ -8.638066, 52.660702 ], [ -8.736394, 52.676235 ], [ -8.542089, 52.683432 ], [ -8.486797, 52.717419 ], [ -8.358258, 52.682648 ], [ -8.257080, 52.697682 ], [ -8.180698, 52.666545 ], [ -8.197941, 52.521333 ], [ -8.399157, 52.468464 ], [ -8.388968, 52.438751 ], [ -8.230361, 52.404265 ], [ -8.160320, 52.302731 ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "Longford" } , "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -7.471810, 53.835936 ], [ -7.394715, 53.781713 ], [ -7.390725, 53.735827 ], [ -7.591442, 53.647545 ], [ -7.658348, 53.531119 ], [ -7.846454, 53.538601 ], [ -7.952620, 53.512380 ], [ -8.025938, 53.607359 ], [ -7.978912, 53.694999 ], [ -7.887424, 53.772237 ], [ -7.899109, 53.815558 ], [ -7.822370, 53.819477 ], [ -7.663122, 53.937114 ], [ -7.606476, 53.937257 ], [ -7.577762, 53.872702 ], [ -7.471810, 53.835936 ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "Louth" } , "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -6.238576, 53.778721 ], [ -6.339042, 53.722788 ], [ -6.481475, 53.722788 ], [ -6.561562, 53.771453 ], [ -6.616427, 53.861516 ], [ -6.687038, 53.875481 ], [ -6.753302, 53.900348 ], [ -6.753231, 53.901916 ], [ -6.679699, 53.909469 ], [ -6.584434, 54.051902 ], [ -6.470146, 54.078835 ], [ -6.374739, 54.066366 ], [ -6.279760, 54.109901 ], [ -6.100846, 53.999603 ], [ -6.164688, 53.976802 ], [ -6.352508, 54.011502 ], [ -6.377518, 53.955711 ], [ -6.333627, 53.877049 ], [ -6.238576, 53.861801 ], [ -6.238576, 53.778721 ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "Mayo" } , "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -9.138043, 54.130707 ], [ -8.963404, 54.145527 ], [ -9.027317, 54.030241 ], [ -8.913598, 54.017701 ], [ -8.835078, 53.972455 ], [ -8.661294, 54.025681 ], [ -8.590398, 53.968109 ], [ -8.682599, 53.958704 ], [ -8.608211, 53.885884 ], [ -8.690223, 53.874484 ], [ -8.696279, 53.722716 ], [ -8.814985, 53.663292 ], [ -8.983425, 53.621895 ], [ -9.117023, 53.486800 ], [ -9.203239, 53.487442 ], [ -9.265798, 53.544301 ], [ -9.409727, 53.541095 ], [ -9.610587, 53.632725 ], [ -9.669727, 53.614912 ], [ -9.774183, 53.600661 ], [ -9.915832, 53.656238 ], [ -9.912483, 53.752286 ], [ -9.651272, 53.800453 ], [ -9.554084, 53.889874 ], [ -9.764706, 53.900134 ], [ -9.905857, 53.861231 ], [ -10.066388, 53.971814 ], [ -10.259196, 53.973453 ], [ -10.189155, 54.015706 ], [ -10.100803, 54.000671 ], [ -9.974188, 54.030669 ], [ -9.966421, 53.951009 ], [ -9.838025, 53.960414 ], [ -9.993639, 54.102633 ], [ -9.899729, 54.117953 ], [ -10.012521, 54.226541 ], [ -10.010312, 54.181296 ], [ -10.129161, 54.096007 ], [ -10.055843, 54.218204 ], [ -10.109709, 54.238511 ], [ -9.995777, 54.309336 ], [ -9.880277, 54.257607 ], [ -9.805819, 54.344606 ], [ -9.382509, 54.294302 ], [ -9.341967, 54.327363 ], [ -9.211931, 54.285894 ], [ -9.224187, 54.217136 ], [ -9.159703, 54.201816 ], [ -9.138043, 54.130707 ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "Meath" } , "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -6.687038, 53.875481 ], [ -6.616427, 53.861516 ], [ -6.561562, 53.771453 ], [ -6.481475, 53.722788 ], [ -6.339042, 53.722788 ], [ -6.238576, 53.778721 ], [ -6.213638, 53.635504 ], [ -6.291089, 53.579998 ], [ -6.408085, 53.563468 ], [ -6.320516, 53.495493 ], [ -6.334767, 53.452528 ], [ -6.453473, 53.376858 ], [ -6.495512, 53.384126 ], [ -6.713757, 53.426378 ], [ -6.840586, 53.390539 ], [ -7.032112, 53.514019 ], [ -6.962926, 53.639494 ], [ -7.250928, 53.711387 ], [ -7.275153, 53.783851 ], [ -6.955730, 53.766893 ], [ -6.942976, 53.874982 ], [ -6.779095, 53.873842 ], [ -6.753302, 53.900348 ], [ -6.687038, 53.875481 ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "Monaghan" } , "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -6.584434, 54.051902 ], [ -6.679699, 53.909469 ], [ -6.753231, 53.901916 ], [ -7.035960, 54.086530 ], [ -7.188226, 54.079548 ], [ -7.311848, 54.114105 ], [ -7.237746, 54.203455 ], [ -7.142268, 54.227325 ], [ -7.202120, 54.297722 ], [ -7.025129, 54.416143 ], [ -6.876141, 54.345247 ], [ -6.795555, 54.211649 ], [ -6.636377, 54.172745 ], [ -6.670293, 54.070570 ], [ -6.584434, 54.051902 ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "Offaly" } , "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -6.997626, 53.317006 ], [ -7.097237, 53.164598 ], [ -7.265606, 53.140230 ], [ -7.354813, 53.202647 ], [ -7.541708, 53.181271 ], [ -7.617948, 53.144790 ], [ -7.555246, 53.100115 ], [ -7.692264, 52.982335 ], [ -7.822513, 52.956256 ], [ -7.922337, 52.862560 ], [ -8.013326, 52.909729 ], [ -7.956681, 52.952907 ], [ -7.904738, 53.092491 ], [ -8.068404, 53.175642 ], [ -7.956538, 53.216256 ], [ -8.020095, 53.261501 ], [ -8.021734, 53.303326 ], [ -7.915640, 53.353416 ], [ -7.767649, 53.329048 ], [ -7.586953, 53.383770 ], [ -7.535224, 53.333751 ], [ -7.372769, 53.317719 ], [ -7.337927, 53.350709 ], [ -7.136140, 53.409563 ], [ -6.997626, 53.317006 ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "Roscommon" } , "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -8.133671, 54.101422 ], [ -8.040972, 54.077125 ], [ -8.100895, 53.953859 ], [ -8.000359, 53.926712 ], [ -7.899109, 53.815558 ], [ -7.887424, 53.772237 ], [ -7.978912, 53.694999 ], [ -8.025938, 53.607359 ], [ -7.952620, 53.512380 ], [ -7.915640, 53.353416 ], [ -8.021734, 53.303326 ], [ -8.020095, 53.261501 ], [ -8.129753, 53.262427 ], [ -8.152838, 53.328478 ], [ -8.242046, 53.361040 ], [ -8.263208, 53.516085 ], [ -8.438631, 53.687660 ], [ -8.611489, 53.709535 ], [ -8.664358, 53.670916 ], [ -8.814985, 53.663292 ], [ -8.696279, 53.722716 ], [ -8.690223, 53.874484 ], [ -8.608211, 53.885884 ], [ -8.682599, 53.958704 ], [ -8.590398, 53.968109 ], [ -8.459722, 53.916024 ], [ -8.373008, 53.919088 ], [ -8.275606, 54.047627 ], [ -8.170794, 54.102633 ], [ -8.133671, 54.101422 ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "Sligo" } , "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -8.373863, 54.468228 ], [ -8.377782, 54.348453 ], [ -8.310591, 54.272855 ], [ -8.333463, 54.185500 ], [ -8.170794, 54.102633 ], [ -8.275606, 54.047627 ], [ -8.373008, 53.919088 ], [ -8.459722, 53.916024 ], [ -8.590398, 53.968109 ], [ -8.661294, 54.025681 ], [ -8.835078, 53.972455 ], [ -8.913598, 54.017701 ], [ -9.027317, 54.030241 ], [ -8.963404, 54.145527 ], [ -9.138043, 54.130707 ], [ -9.057528, 54.295442 ], [ -8.930271, 54.294302 ], [ -8.827526, 54.253474 ], [ -8.661935, 54.272641 ], [ -8.583629, 54.207944 ], [ -8.508601, 54.217349 ], [ -8.626381, 54.255113 ], [ -8.681886, 54.355935 ], [ -8.490289, 54.418209 ], [ -8.469697, 54.470437 ], [ -8.373863, 54.468228 ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "Tipperary" } , "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -8.013326, 52.909729 ], [ -7.922337, 52.862560 ], [ -7.822513, 52.956256 ], [ -7.692264, 52.982335 ], [ -7.656923, 52.939370 ], [ -7.686564, 52.851444 ], [ -7.649370, 52.790809 ], [ -7.454139, 52.640253 ], [ -7.386663, 52.502451 ], [ -7.400130, 52.455496 ], [ -7.338853, 52.342561 ], [ -7.545271, 52.355671 ], [ -7.760524, 52.314986 ], [ -7.722190, 52.222216 ], [ -7.944426, 52.236466 ], [ -8.088569, 52.215518 ], [ -8.160320, 52.302731 ], [ -8.230361, 52.404265 ], [ -8.388968, 52.438751 ], [ -8.399157, 52.468464 ], [ -8.197941, 52.521333 ], [ -8.180698, 52.666545 ], [ -8.257080, 52.697682 ], [ -8.358258, 52.682648 ], [ -8.486797, 52.717419 ], [ -8.415403, 52.895906 ], [ -8.315365, 52.923338 ], [ -8.301399, 53.004138 ], [ -8.068404, 53.175642 ], [ -7.904738, 53.092491 ], [ -7.956681, 52.952907 ], [ -8.013326, 52.909729 ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "Waterford" } , "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -7.545271, 52.355671 ], [ -7.338853, 52.342561 ], [ -7.191717, 52.251857 ], [ -6.975182, 52.291544 ], [ -6.958651, 52.241525 ], [ -6.949175, 52.177612 ], [ -7.019714, 52.134006 ], [ -7.088615, 52.150679 ], [ -7.426921, 52.129588 ], [ -7.551398, 52.077645 ], [ -7.585243, 51.991501 ], [ -7.731951, 51.937635 ], [ -7.849731, 51.978747 ], [ -7.927468, 51.990147 ], [ -8.137519, 52.159086 ], [ -8.088569, 52.215518 ], [ -7.944426, 52.236466 ], [ -7.722190, 52.222216 ], [ -7.760524, 52.314986 ], [ -7.545271, 52.355671 ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "Westmeath" } , "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -7.282350, 53.795394 ], [ -7.275153, 53.783851 ], [ -7.250928, 53.711387 ], [ -6.962926, 53.639494 ], [ -7.032112, 53.514019 ], [ -7.136140, 53.409563 ], [ -7.337927, 53.350709 ], [ -7.372769, 53.317719 ], [ -7.535224, 53.333751 ], [ -7.586953, 53.383770 ], [ -7.767649, 53.329048 ], [ -7.915640, 53.353416 ], [ -7.952620, 53.512380 ], [ -7.846454, 53.538601 ], [ -7.658348, 53.531119 ], [ -7.591442, 53.647545 ], [ -7.390725, 53.735827 ], [ -7.394715, 53.781713 ], [ -7.282350, 53.795394 ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "Wexford" } , "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -6.958651, 52.241525 ], [ -6.975182, 52.291544 ], [ -6.916185, 52.446304 ], [ -6.810019, 52.481218 ], [ -6.717890, 52.633128 ], [ -6.614788, 52.654218 ], [ -6.592415, 52.708085 ], [ -6.446419, 52.698466 ], [ -6.325575, 52.799145 ], [ -6.144666, 52.770716 ], [ -6.225822, 52.648447 ], [ -6.193046, 52.562944 ], [ -6.353577, 52.408469 ], [ -6.358066, 52.344271 ], [ -6.465799, 52.377902 ], [ -6.429176, 52.293753 ], [ -6.311396, 52.240955 ], [ -6.358636, 52.174049 ], [ -6.489170, 52.190722 ], [ -6.596975, 52.169561 ], [ -6.706917, 52.217656 ], [ -6.836382, 52.216801 ], [ -6.823058, 52.174833 ], [ -6.931361, 52.122392 ], [ -6.903644, 52.201268 ], [ -6.958651, 52.241525 ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "Wicklow" } , "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -6.347948, 53.200936 ], [ -6.105263, 53.219391 ], [ -6.041421, 53.117928 ], [ -6.046409, 52.989887 ], [ -5.996960, 52.963738 ], [ -6.057524, 52.857358 ], [ -6.144666, 52.770716 ], [ -6.325575, 52.799145 ], [ -6.446419, 52.698466 ], [ -6.592415, 52.708085 ], [ -6.631176, 52.831494 ], [ -6.512470, 52.826791 ], [ -6.463234, 52.893982 ], [ -6.712332, 52.924335 ], [ -6.745464, 53.017747 ], [ -6.592771, 53.092704 ], [ -6.464161, 53.228939 ], [ -6.347948, 53.200936 ] ] ] } }
    ]
  }
}

function newMap(){
  return {
    "type": "FeatureCollection", 
    "features": [
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "Carlow" } , "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -6.592415, 52.708085 ], [ -6.614788, 52.654218 ], [ -6.717890, 52.633128 ], [ -6.810019, 52.481218 ], [ -6.916185, 52.446304 ], [ -6.914688, 52.590519 ], [ -6.975609, 52.653791 ], [ -6.952951, 52.705377 ], [ -7.090468, 52.732311 ], [ -7.072441, 52.797934 ], [ -7.065957, 52.822872 ], [ -6.915828, 52.856717 ], [ -6.735489, 52.884007 ], [ -6.712332, 52.924335 ], [ -6.463234, 52.893982 ], [ -6.512470, 52.826791 ], [ -6.631176, 52.831494 ], [ -6.592415, 52.708085 ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": {  "id": "Cavan" } , "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -7.311848, 54.114105 ], [ -7.188226, 54.079548 ], [ -7.035960, 54.086530 ], [ -6.753231, 53.901916 ], [ -6.753302, 53.900348 ], [ -6.779095, 53.873842 ], [ -6.942976, 53.874982 ], [ -6.955730, 53.766893 ], [ -7.275153, 53.783851 ], [ -7.282350, 53.795394 ], [ -7.394715, 53.781713 ], [ -7.471810, 53.835936 ], [ -7.577762, 53.872702 ], [ -7.606476, 53.937257 ], [ -7.604552, 54.005160 ], [ -7.760239, 54.105127 ], [ -7.853223, 54.098144 ], [ -8.034560, 54.238796 ], [ -7.952976, 54.306628 ], [ -7.878090, 54.289172 ], [ -7.820589, 54.199180 ], [ -7.696967, 54.202529 ], [ -7.554248, 54.127999 ], [ -7.414737, 54.150800 ], [ -7.311848, 54.114105 ] ] ] } }
    ]
  }
}
let cleanHover = function () {
    d3.selectAll("path")
        .transition()
        .duration(200)
        .style("stroke", "transparent")
}

let mouseOver = function (event, d) {
    var countryCode = event.target.id;
    cleanHover();
    d3.selectAll("path#" + countryCode)
        .transition()
        .duration(200)
        .style("opacity", 1)
        .style("stroke", "black")

    tip.show(event, d);

}

let mouseLeave = function () {
    cleanHover();
    tip.hide();
}

let resetMap = function(){
    svg.selectAll("*").remove();
    d3.select("svg").call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity);
}

let loadSmallMap = function(){
    resetMap();
  const mapJson = newMap();
  var projection = d3.geoMercator();
  var features = mapJson.features;

  //Projections
  var geoPath = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);

  projection.fitSize([width, height], { "type": "FeatureCollection", "features": features })

  svg.selectAll("path")
    .data(features)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", geoPath)
    .attr("id", function (d) { return d.properties.id })
    .style("fill", 'steelblue')
    .style("stroke", "transparent")
    .on("mouseover", mouseOver)
    .on("mouseleave", mouseLeave)
    .call(tip);
}


    var zoom = d3.zoom()
        .on('zoom', (event) => {
            svg.attr('transform', event.transform);
        })
        .scaleExtent([1, 1]);
    var width = 560;
    var height = 350;

    var svg = d3.select("#mapDiv")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .style("background-color", "white")
        .style("border", "solid 1px black")
        .call(zoom)
        .append("g")
        
      

        ;

    const tip = d3.tip()
        .attr("class", "d3-tip")
        .html((event, d) => "red"); 

        const mapJson = roi();
        var projection = d3.geoMercator();
        var features = mapJson.features;

        //Projections
        var geoPath = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);

        projection.fitSize([width, height], { "type": "FeatureCollection", "features": features })

        svg.selectAll("path")
            .data(features)
            .enter()
            .append("path")
            .attr("d", geoPath)
            .attr("id", function (d) { return d.properties.id })
            .style("fill", 'steelblue')
            .style("stroke", "transparent")
            .on("mouseover", mouseOver)
            .on("mouseleave", mouseLeave)
            .call(tip);
```

```html
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/bumbeishvili/d3-tip-for-v6@4/d3-tip.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/bumbeishvili/d3-tip-for-v6@4/d3-tip.min.css">
<center id="mapDiv">
<input id="button" type="button" value="Load Small Map" onclick="loadSmallMap()"/>
</center>
```

Comment: Thank you for help Andrew. I have already accepted your answer and it worked wonder. Do you mind if I ask you another related questions? I changed `ScaleExtend` to `[1,2]` to enable zooming. It seems like that the zoom state is cached for each continent in my case somehow. For example, if I zoomed in the Asian countries map, then load the world map, then load the Asian countries map, it is still zoomed. However, if I zoomed in the Asian countries, then load the world map, then load the Europe country, the zoom is reset. Do you have an insight why?

Comment: nvm, it has to do with my code.  I overthought about it. Thanks a lot